# Changing Category Names

Tags: category, seo

If you change the name of a category on Magento and enter a new URL underneath and tick the box: Create Permanent Redirect for old URL then does this mean that all URL's which contain the old URL will redirect to the new name of the category & URL?

Would this be ok from an SEO perspective?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Tommy,

This would not only be OK from a SEO perspective, this is actually quite **necessary**.

Without it you would have 404's on the old url's and that's bad.

Next to that you ensure a better experience for your site visitors. If you have hard-linked to these categories from for instance a cms page or blog post, you ensure that even though the category URL has changed, they still get to the right page instead of being thrown a 404.

Comment: So essentially this is a quick way of setting up a 301 redirect?

Comment: Yes. You can check `Catalog -> URL Rewrite management` for the list of redirects and the redirect method that Magento generates for you.

Comment: For some reason the 301 redirect hasn't come up in the URL Rewrite Management? I changed the category name and changed the URL and ensured that the Create Permanent Redirect for old URL was ticked. Magento hasn't yet updated the category name yet though.

Comment: Have you set `system -> General -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites` set to `YES` ??

Comment: Yes, it is set to YES

Comment: Then I suggest you reindex your url rewrites. `system -> Index Management`, and flush your cache after that. If that doesn't help, you should open a new question on this specific issue.

Comment: @Tommy Did that help? If yes, you should accept this answer.